# What Kind of airfoil configuration is preferred for an hyper sonic plane?

Tags: aircraft-design

I am trying to design a hyper sonic aircraft in line with X-15 for my Aircraft design project. This requires me to figure out the preferred airfoil shape for the wing.

Comment: If there was one optimal shape for all situations, this would be easy to answer, as it's written it's impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this question has to be on hold, [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersonic_airfoils) provides a seemingly valid answer to this broad question: "*Supersonic airfoils generally have a thin section formed of either angled planes or opposed arcs (called "double wedge airfoils" and "biconvex airfoils" respectively), with very sharp leading and trailing edges*".

Answer (score 1):

At hypersonic speed the local drag grows with the inclination of the local surface against the free stream. Thus, the best shape is a thin wedge. Drag will scale with the cube of the thickness ratio of the wedge.

Depending on the maximum tolerable heat load, you should choose a pointed leading edge (highest heat load, smallest drag) or a blunt leading edge, where the separated shock will reduce local heat loads, albeit at the price of much higher drag.

Ideally, past its maximum thickness the airfoil tapers down towards a thin trailing edge, and again a wedge shape will cause the least amount of drag.

In the picture below ([source](http://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/MuseumExhibits/FactSheets/Display/tabid/509/Article/195761/north-american-x-15a-2.aspx)) you can barely see the tip airfoil of the X-15:

[image: North American X-15]

It used a simple, blunt wedge at the vertical tails because the vacuum at the rear face provided additional directional stability. However, for lowest drag, a double wedge of the smallest thickness possible should be used.